# window.parent.postMessage causes main window to modify window history

Tags: javascript, html5-history

Im currently have an iframe with my application and i tried using

```
 window.parent.postMessage
```

to communicate between the main window and subscribe an event for me to know if Iframe sent a message but my problem is that it modifies the browser history like adding new window history that why if i clicked back onto my browser it reloads the page i want to prevent from adding window history by my iframe i there a way to do it?

i have tried searching to the new but i didnt find anything

Comment: can you show a minimal example that demonstrates this - because I can't make `postMessage` do anything to `history`

Comment: @JaromandaX hello i think i miss something it looks like the Iframe is the one responsible for adding a history entry it request a get onto my main URL

Comment: without code ... your guess is better than anyone elses